# upgrade from compiled package in Slackware

Tags: php, linux, slackware

I compiled php 5.2.17  from the source with php-fpm and I have the compiled package /tmp
as you know the version of php is slackware 13.1 is the same (5.2.17 without php-fpm) .
How could I update from from compiled package?

Answer (score 1):

Best idea would be editing Slackware's php.SlackBuild, creating new package and using upgradepkg to upgrade it.

Comment: I did the first part I need the help with second part /  how to use upgradepkg / I did php.SlackBuild and I creat the compiled packages in temp folder what should I do now

Comment: If you have your package in /tmp like /tmp/php-5.2.17-i486-1_slack13.2.txz then you do just upgradepkg /tmp/php-5.2.17-i486-1_slack13.1.txz as root. If you didn't change build number then you need to add --reinstall switch. Check manpages: man upgradepkg

Answer (score 1):

The very easy way is, remove your old packages first then install your fresh packages then :) It's so easy right ? :D

Btw @APC, how do you create new packages ? Using slackbuild script ? Or manualy ? If you use SlackBuild script, which SlackBuild script do you use ? From Slackware installer or from SBo site ?